# Windows Input Simulator or Send Keys will not work on a Console app that opens another console

Tags: c#, input, sdk, monitor, sendkeys

So I'm making a script that monitors a folder where apps come, and I want them to be deployed using a console SDK, The console SDK has it's own commands so i have to input them.

The monitor works, after it sees something in the folder it opens up the SDK, but then Input simulator or Send key commands do nothing.

```
while (path == null)
        {

            Run();

        }
        if (path != null)
        {
            toOpen();
        }


    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {

            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (Test Scanner)");
            string args = @"E:\Test Scanner";

            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = args;
            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
               the renaming of files or directories. */
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine(path);
             // Wait for the software to quit the program.
            //Console.WriteLine("Wait for System String Deploy to procede");


    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        //Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        path = e.FullPath.ToString();
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);

    }
    private static void toOpen() {

        string toOpen = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Durango XDK\xdk\Command Prompts\Xbox One XDK Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(toOpen); 

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("xbconnect" + "127.0.0.1");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("xbapp deploy" + path);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Send Keys example:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(toOpen); 

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SendKeys.SendWait("xbconnect 127.0.0.1");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        SendKeys.SendWait("xbapp deploy" + path);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Any idea why it might not work.

Note: There might be brackets closed, as this is not the full script and i just copy pasted a piece.

Answer (score 0):

The Console App was not running under administrator privileges. Thus I couldn't write inside XDK which was running as admin.

This was solved adding an App.manifest